# Die of pig measles vs. Die of the pig measles

Tags: definite-articles

I am editing a short story text that was written in the the 1930's. The setting is rural, and the characters are somewhat backwards. One character advises an acquaintance to die "of the pig measles" rather than from consumption, because the former is so much quicker. This sounds incorrect to me. To die "of the measles" would sound right, but he's talking about a particular strain of the measles, i.e. pig measles, therefore I think it should just be to die "of pig measles", but I'm loathe to tamper with the historical text. Can anybody help? Oh, the idiom is supposed to be British English more than American English.

Comment: Would that not be pork measles?

Comment: Pork is the meat; pig is the animal.

Comment: I have seen more references to pork measles than to pig measles, but in this (geographic) setting, it is definitely pig measles.

Comment: Even if the curse says 'pig measles,' both consumption and measly pork are wasting diseases; and putting the two together would make sense.  But  don't change it on that account: it's a fine threat.

Answer (score 4):

The particularity of the strain of a disease doesn't tell you whether to use a determinative.  As an example, take consumption.  The google finds no results for "die of the pulmonary tuberculosis" and 30.8K hits for "die of pulmonary tuberculosis."  The same search for "swine flu," on the other hand, turns up both usages.

The Ngram viewer [finds](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=die%20of%20measles%2Cdie%20of%20the%20measles&year_start=1920&year_end=1940&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdie%20of%20measles%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdie%20of%20the%20measles%3B%2Cc0) that although the phrasing "die of measles" has always been more popular than "die of the measles," for a few years in the 1930s they came fairly close to parity.

I think the lesson is not to tamper with contemporaneous dialog, especially that which has corroboration from the era in question.

(Warning: the google searches will have false drops from headlines, and the Ngram viewer is not necessarily a representative sample of books, and books need not reflect all usage.)